# nsenterで起動したプロセスについて

Tags: docker

`nsenter` (`docker-enter` ) で入った Docker のコンテナ内で、 `service httpd start` したところ、その `nsenter` した元の CoreOS へのセッションを切るとコンテナ自体は生きているのですが、 `apache` プロセスが死んでしまいます。

これはどのような挙動なのでしょうか？

ちなみに、同じことを `docker attach` して、<kbd>Ctrl＋PQ</kbd>で抜けると大丈夫なようです。

環境としては GCE の CoreOSです。

Comment: どこかにエラーが発生したことをしめすログは出力されていませんか？

Comment: ログはapacheをdebugモードで起動しても何のメッセージも吐かれず突然落ちているようです。。